# How to send get request to a web API using CURL?

Tags: api, curl, postman, webapi

I have a Web API and it works fine when I send get requests to it using Postman. For example, the API can handle this request:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/test/?id=23
```

When I try the same exact thing with curl (`$ curl http://localhost:5000/api/test/?id=23`), I get this error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Try to export the curl via Postman's code feature. Maybe there are headers in your request in Postman, which you are not sending in your curl.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Thank you, How can I do that? I see Import in the Postman, but not the Export.

Comment: You need to press code: https://cdn.softwaretestinghelp.com/wp-content/qa/uploads/2020/01/Postman-SelectRequestToExportAsCode1.jpg

Comment: I just ran your curl statement (`curl http://localhost:5000/api/test/?id=23`) and got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused` because I'm not running anything on the port... the statement ought to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Probably your app supports only POST requests?
`curl http://localhost:5000/api/test/?id=23` will send GET request.

Try

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/test/?id=23
```

If that does not work, the reason is probably in request headers, cookies, or (unlikely) user-agent handling in the API.

Comment: `?id=23` indicates a `GET` so why would you send it as a `POST`??

Comment: It's certainly not a good practice but this is possible and would be the first thing to check for me.

Comment: Valid point. I would argue that without context, people stumbling on this without knowledge of HTTP request methods may not be helped. so maybe a little added explanation?